# Shortcut to minimize all windows on OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut to minimize all windows like in Windows? In Windows it's <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 9):

There is no shortcut to **minimize** all windows of **all** applications. Some alternatives:

- To **hide (all windows of) all applications** but the current one, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>, or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd>-click on another application's window. If you <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> while in an application with no windows up, this will have the effect of hiding all windows.

  Hiding an application is distinct from minimizing its windows; the application's windows will not appear in the Dock, and all of them will reappear the next time you switch to that application.
- To **minimize all windows of the current application**, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, or <kbd>⌥</kbd>-click on the minimize box [image: minimize box].

  (In general, the <kbd>⌥</kbd> key often means “apply to all”, especially for windows.)
- To **reveal the desktop**, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Mission Control key</kbd> (shared with F3), or use a separate keyboard, mouse button, or screen corner shortcut set in System Preferences → Mission Control → Show Desktop.

  While in Show Desktop mode, existing windows are pushed off the edges of the screen but newly-created windows (such as from menu commands in the current application) can be interacted with. Switching applications, except to the Finder, will cancel Show Desktop mode.

Answer (score 6):

There's no exact substitute. Mac OS X is designed more around applications with multiple windows each, e.g. in the separation of application switcher `(Shift-)Cmd-Tab` and window-cycling `(Shift-)Cmd-Backtick`, while windows is designed more around windows (largely, but the Windows 7 taskbar recognizes related application windows).

You can press F11 (or Fn-F11, depending on the configuration in *System Preferences » Keyboard*) to move all windows out of the way to get access to the desktop (part of Exposé, configure in *System Preferences » Exposé & Spaces*), or press `Cmd-Opt-H` to hide all applications but the currently active one. To minimize the currently active application's windows, press `Cmd-Opt-M`, or select *Window » Minimize All* while keeping `Opt` pressed.

---

The following AppleScript hides all applications but one -- it doesn't seem to be possible to hide all of them.

```
tell application "System Events" to set visible of every application process to false
```

---

The following AppleScript should minimize all windows. It can be a real pain to restore them though.

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with p in every application process whose visible is true
        click (first button of every window of p whose role description is "minimize button")
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: About the second Applescript: in iTunes 10 `button 3` is close. It could be better to `tell application ␣ to set miniaturized of windows whose miniaturizable is true to true` (or `collapsed` for Finder).

Comment: @Lri Have you tested that? I tried it but couldn't get it to work. An `application process'` windows don't have these regular window properties.

Comment: You'd have to convert that list of application processes to applications first. (Or find some other way to get the open applications.)

Comment: @Lri Tried that via the `application file`, but didn't work. I don't like the `button 3` solution either, but it's the only think that worked. `(p as application)` doesn't work either.

Comment: Convert the `application file` (or `file`) from alias to text first.

Answer (score 5):

Could also be useful: [What are the differences between minimizing and hiding an application? - Apple - Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9048/what-are-the-differences-between-minimizing-and-hiding-an-application/9118#9118).

Another Applescript for minimizing all windows:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set procs to file of processes whose visible is true
end tell
repeat with proc in procs
    set proc to proc as text
    try
        tell application proc to set (miniaturized of windows whose miniaturizable is true) to true
    end try
end repeat
tell application "Finder" to set collapsed of windows to true
```

Comment: Odd. Tried that (or at least similar), didn't work for me. Much nicer than `click button 3`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do this.  I double checked on Mavericks and El Capitan, one of the following three ways will work:

1. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> and then <kbd>M</kbd>
2. <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>
3. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd>

using the first method, all windows will be hidden. For method 2 and 3, all windows are hidden temporarily -- if you click on any app, then all windows will come back.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the key code for F11 in applescript.  Special thanks to 
https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes
for helping me figure this out.

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 103
end tell
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! There is no need to tag your answers :) PS Did you post another version of this before? I could swear I saw it but cannot find it now.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome.  Yes I did!  I deleted it due to noob errors.  Speaking of noob errors thanks for the advice around tags - in fact that's why I deleted the earlier one.  After I posted it, I realized I could add tags.