# Minimize all windows in OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook-pro, window

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shortcut to minimize all windows on OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/266067/shortcut-to-minimize-all-windows-on-os-x)

Hi all, how do we minimize all the windows in MacBook Pro? I do not mean the 4 fingers swipe up because that doesn't really minimize all windows. What I want to do is to minimize all windows and keep 1 window open (in windows its simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> + click on the taskbar once)

Answer (score 3):

You could create an applescript to do the task. Then simply add the applescript to your dock.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set visible of every process whose visible is true to false
end tell
```

Try that!

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to do this is alt-tab to the finder, then option-command-m

There isn't a single key combination to minimize all windows - option-command-m minimizes the windows of all other applications

Comment: No, option-command-M minimizes all windows in the *current* application. You're thinking of option-command-H, which *hides* all other applications.

Comment: Good point... he's right you know ;-)